# Jquery UI tabs - Custom "Loader" for AJAX tabs

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following code to generate Jquery UI tabs:

```
<div id="tabs-loading-message" style="display:none">Loading, Please wait..</div>
<div id="fragment-2">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="/public/animalstab" title="Animals"><span>Animals</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="/public/birdstab" title="Birds"><span>Birds</span></a></li>
    </ul>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#tabs-loading-message").show();    
        $('#fragment-2').tabs(
    {
        cache:false, spinner:'', selected: 0 ,
        select: function(event,ui) {
            //show spinner
            $("#tabs-loading-message").show();                
        },
        load: function() {
          //  hide spinner
           $("#tabs-loading-message").hide();               
        }
    }
);
});

</script>
```

I am able to display the loading message, but how can I hide the contents of the tab panel, when it's selected and show the contents when loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can catch success event from ajax:

```
.tabs({ajaxOptions: {success: function() {
    $("#tabs-loading-message").hide();
}}});
```